# I want to install a library which requires a python version and, having two installed, finds the wrong one

Tags: debian, python

I want to install a library on my debian machine and it requires a python version above 2.6.6-7. The machine had installed the version 2.5.2-3, so I installed python 2.7.

When I run python -V, the output is "Python 2.7", but when I try to install the library, it outputs "Version of python on system is 2.5.2-3.". How can I solve this?

The library I'm using is paramiko, in order to use ssh communication. If, instead of solving the above, you could suggest another library which works with python 2.5, it would be apreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: Lenny has been EOL for over a year.

Comment: How did you install `python 2.7`? I suspect you installed it to `/usr/local` which is why your library cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you install from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko) you have to make sure that your `easy-install` or `pip` uses the right version of Python, e.g. by using:

```
pip-2.7 install paramiko
```

If you install from an extracted source file, I recommend you explicitly use `python2.7` or use the full path to the `python2.7` executable.

```
sudo python2.7 setup.py install
```